# How to enable DRM in chromedriver headless mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, drm

I am aware that there is no official support for DRM-protected content (e.g. Spotify webplayer, netflix, etc.) when using headless chromedriver.

Has anyone here gotten it to work despite the aforementioned limitation?

I went as far as using a custom profile in headless chromedriver (one that should include WidevineCdm), but so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: replacing Chromiuim's default libwidevine binary with one extracted from ChromeOS.

1. Download the latest ChromeOS [libwidevine](http://blog.vpetkov.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/libwidevinecdm.so_.zip) binary and extract it.
2. Copy the extracted *libwidevinecdm.so* to */usr/lib/chromium-browser*.
3. Change the access permissions to 755 (`chmod 755 libwidevinecdm.so`)

Credits to [vpetkovs's blog post](https://blog.vpetkov.net/2019/07/12/netflix-and-spotify-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-with-latest-default-chromium/) for finding this bright solution.

Comment: It has been a while so unfortunately I am not sure anymore.

Comment: Any update on this? I can't run netflix headless using python + selenium using a PI

Comment: @JeffersonSantos the accepted answer is what worked for me.

Comment: What is your scenario? I have PIs (ARM64) with a python script (python + selenium). When I try to run headless with Chrome or Firefox drivers, I get the "Perdon" message. If I run in my windows PC headless with Chrome, happens the same, however, with firefox driver on win PC I can do it headless.

Comment: It's been a while so I don't remember all the details, but I had it running on a Raspberry PI with Python and Selenium as well.